# How do i use 'step into' in eclipse on a mac book air without an f5 key

Tags: eclipse

I am developing using eclipse helios on a mac book air. I want to step into the code using <kbd>F5</kbd> but there is no <kbd>F5</kbd> on the mac book air. anyone one know what I should press?

Comment: The button to the trash chute to throw your mac into. In all seriousness though, isnt there a way to rebind the step into key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebind the key: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys